# Synchronizing tasks

Tags: multithreading, c++11, threadpool

I am develeping an application that uses a threadpool, submits tasks to it and synchronizes them. The main thread has to wait until all the submitted tasks from a single loop iteration finish and then it submits another bunch of tasks (because the tasks from the next iteration operate on the same data and they will be dependent on one another).

My question is, what is the best way to do that?

So far, what I have come up with is  that each thread, after finishing a task, increments an atomic unsigned integer. When the integer equals the number of submitted tasks, the main thread continues its work and submits another round of tasks.

This is my first multithreaded application. 
Is this an optimal and sensible way of dealing with this problem.

I'm using a threadpool class copied from an excellent book "C++ Concurrency in Action: by Anthony Williams.

Here are the classes:

```
class thread_pool
{
    std::atomic_bool done;
    thread_safe_queue<std::function<void()> > work_queue;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    join_threads joiner;

    void worker_thread()
    {
        while(!done)
        {
            std::function<void()> task;
            if(work_queue.try_pop(task))
            {
                task();
            }
            else
            {
                std::this_thread::yield();
            }
        }
    }
public:
    thread_pool():
        done(false),joiner(threads)
    {
        unsigned const thread_count=std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
        try
        {
            for(unsigned i=0;i<thread_count;++i)
            {
                threads.push_back(
                    std::thread(&thread_pool::worker_thread,this));
            }
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            done=true;
            throw;
        }
    }

    ~thread_pool()
    {
        done=true;
    }

    template<typename FunctionType>
    void submit(FunctionType f)
    {
        work_queue.push(std::function<void()>(f));
    }
};

template<typename T>
class threadsafe_queue
{
private:
    mutable std::mutex mut;
    std::queue<T> data_queue;
    std::condition_variable data_cond;
public:
    threadsafe_queue()
    {}

    void push(T new_value)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        data_queue.push(std::move(new_value));
        data_cond.notify_one();
    }

    void wait_and_pop(T& value)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        data_cond.wait(lk, [this]{return !data_queue.empty(); });
        value = std::move(data_queue.front());
        data_queue.pop();
    }

    std::shared_ptr<T> wait_and_pop()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        data_cond.wait(lk, [this]{return !data_queue.empty(); });
        std::shared_ptr<T> res(
            std::make_shared<T>(std::move(data_queue.front())));
        data_queue.pop();
        return res;
    }

    bool try_pop(T& value)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        if (data_queue.empty())
            return false;
        value = std::move(data_queue.front());
        data_queue.pop();
    }

    std::shared_ptr<T> try_pop()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        if (data_queue.empty())
            return std::shared_ptr<T>();
        std::shared_ptr<T> res(
            std::make_shared<T>(std::move(data_queue.front())));
        data_queue.pop();
        return res;
    }

    bool empty() const
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        return data_queue.empty();
    }
};
```

The main() function:

```
std::condition_variable waitForThreads;
std::mutex mut;

std::atomic<unsigned> doneCount = 0;

unsigned threadCount = 4; // sample concurrent thread count that I use for testing

 void synchronizeWork()
   {
    doneCount++;
    if (doneCount.load() == threadCount)
    {
        doneCount = 0;
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mut);
        waitForThreads.notify_one();
    }
   }

   void Task_A()
   {
    std::cout << "Task A, thread id: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(3000));
    synchronizeWork();
   }

int main()
{   
    unsigned const thread_count = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    thread_pool threadPool;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < thread_count; j++)
            threadPool.submit(Task_A);

// Below is my way of synchronizing the tasks

        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut);
            waitForThreads.wait(lock);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the threadpool class you are using.

Without using such a class, the usual way to do this looks like this:

```
  std::cout << "Spawning 3 threads...\n";
  std::thread t1 (pause_thread,1);
  std::thread t2 (pause_thread,2);
  std::thread t3 (pause_thread,3);
  std::cout << "Done spawning threads. Now waiting for them to join:\n";
  t1.join();
  t2.join();
  t3.join();
  std::cout << "All threads joined!\n";
```

I would imagine that any decent threadpool class would allow you to the same sort of thing, even more simply, by giving you a metho to block until all the threads have completed.  I suggest you double check the documentation.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to create a new thread each time a task needs to be done because I suppose it would be inefficent (as the same type of task needs to be performed thousands of times).
Instead, a spawned thread checks in a loop if there is any pending tasks in queue and then does the work.

Comment: If the time taken to create a thread is significant, then the sizes of your tasks are too small.  You should combine sufficient tasks into one, so that the thread overhead is not significant.

Comment: The time to finish my task is quite significant as they do molecular dynamics calculations. But I still am not sure if creating a new thread for each iteration is the most elegant way of dealing with this problem, that would seem too easy.
This would mean that I don't need a thread pool at all.

Comment: Elegance is simple and easy.  Complicated and hard is not elegance.  This is also called the KISS principal.  If you do not need a thread pool, then that is a good thing, because you have one less thing to go wrong.

Comment: Thank you.
One last question. Do you, personally, think that thread pool in this situation is not necessary? In my program, the number of tasks will always be equal to the number of threads and they all do the same task.

Comment: I do not know enough about your problem to answer.  I can say that the addition of any extra class should always be justified.  Unless you have a better reason to add a threadpool to your design than it seems elegant, then I would certainly leave it out for the sake of keeping things simple.